# Fix alignment of fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The column headlings don't line up with the fields when editing a record. I would like to know how can I fix the the little boxes so it will be align to the title. I am learning CSS but I provided the code of the html and CSS. If you look at the code there is a section that shows up date, hours, what did you do, work order, and task. I tried editing those sections but unfortunately it dint work.

[image: picture]

```html
<div ng-if="c.options.task && c.loadingSpinner">
  <loading-spinner></loading-spinner>
</div>
<div ng-if="!c.loadingSpinner || !c.options.task">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12 nopadding">
          <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <sp-date-picker ng-model="c.data.taskDate" sn-change="c.dateChange()"></sp-date-picker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input name="hours" ng-model="c.data.taskHours" placeholder="hrs" class="task_input" ng-change="c.hoursChanged()" min="0" type="number" step="any" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 nopadding">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <textarea ng-change="c.descriptionChanged()" name="description" ng-model="c.data.taskDescription" class="task_input" placeholder="description" required>{{taskInput}}</textarea>
                <p class="limiter-text" [ngClass]="{'too-long': descriptionFault, 'too-long-large': stillTooLong}">{{limiterText}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2">

                <input name="q" id="q" type="text" placeholder="Work Order" ng-model="c.data.workOrder"
                       ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}" autocomplete="off"
                       uib-typeahead="wo as wo.label for wo in c.getResults($viewValue) | filter:{title:$viewValue}"
                       typeahead-focus-first="false"
                       typeahead-on-select="c.onSelect($item, $model, $label)"
                       typeahead-template-url="wo-typeahead.html" class="full-text form-control input-typeahead">



              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                <select name="labor-task" class="task_input" ng-change="c.taskSelected()" ng-model="c.data.laborTask">
                  <option disabled value="">select a task</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="option in c.data.displayTasks" value="{{option.sys_id}}">{{option.task}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <button type="button" class="button button_row" ng-click="c.saveClicked()">Save</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="c.cancelClicked()" class="button button_row">Cancel</button>
                <!--<div *ngIf="errorMessage.length > 0" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
{{errorMessage}}
</div>-->
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1">
                <span class="task_status" tooltip="This task has been approved." tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-popup-delay='250'>
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: why don't you table layout for that?

Comment: thank you for your reply. How do I do that? I'm a beginner.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: I would like an example with the code I provided...

Comment: Show us in a picture form, what kind of output are you looking for.

Comment: Yes. I updated the picture. I want the boxes to be align to their corresponding tittle.

Comment: That's pretty much tabular data. So you should use a proper HTML table, or fake it with display:table, table-row, table-cell, etc